# setting output variables on Windows using cmd.exe as the shell

Tags: github-actions

How can i set output variables when using `shell: cmd` on Windows?  My repo is hosted at Github (not Gitlab).

The following is based on this [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59175332/using-output-from-a-previous-job-in-a-new-one-in-a-github-action)

```
jobs:
  job1:
    runs-on: my-windows-machine
    # Map a step output to a job output
    outputs:
      output1: ${{ steps.step1.outputs.test }}
      output2: ${{ steps.step2.outputs.test }}
    steps:
    - id: step1
      run: |
        echo '::echo::on'
        echo "::set-output name=test::hello"
      shell: cmd
    - id: step2
      run: |
        echo '::echo::on'
        echo "::set-output name=test::world"
      shell: cmd
  job2:
    runs-on: my-windows-machine
    needs: job1
    steps:
    - run: echo ok: ${{needs.job1.outputs.output1}} ${{needs.job1.outputs.output2}}
      shell: cmd
```

The echo stmt in job2 only shows `ok:` string if `shell: cmd` is used in the steps in job1.

Comment: For testing, would an [`::echo::on` help](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#echoing-command-outputs)? Command echoing is disabled by default.

Comment: I changed the echo to :
   echo ok: ${{needs.job1.outputs.output1}} ${{needs.job1.outputs.output2}}

The only output i see is "ok:", so there's nothing wrong with the echo stmt

Comment: I agree, but I was not thinking about that echo stmt. I was thinking about the echos done in step 1 or 2.

Comment: Thx... i changed the code (see the updated code snippet) to add that extra `echo '::echo::on'`
I still only see `ok:` in the echo stmt of job2

Comment: I would get back from an official example which is supposed to work, like https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#example-1. And from there, gradually transform it in your own code.

Comment: i guess setting output vars just isn't supported with `cmd.exe`.  I went ahead and broke up the steps in my workflow to use `shell: cmd` for the things that need to be processed by cmd.exe and created a separate step (using the default shell) just to set the output vars.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [OP Andrew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6511046/andrew) concludes in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72407495/setting-output-variables-on-windows-using-cmd-exe-as-the-shell#comment127919790_72407495), output vars just is not supported with `cmd.exe`.

> I went ahead and broke up the steps in my workflow to use `shell: cmd` for the things that need to be processed by `cmd.exe` and created a separate step (using the default shell) just to set the output vars.

---

As an alternative, you can see in "[Github Actions, how to share a calculated value between job steps?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57989070/6309)" the [`$GITHUB_OUTPUT`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#setting-an-output-parameter) command, which can be used to define outputs for steps. The outputs can then be used in later steps and evaluated in `with` and `env` input sections.

You can see it used in "[How can I use a GitHub action's output in a workflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67283976/6309)".

Note: the [older `::set-output` command has now (Oct. 2022) been deprecated](https://github.blog/changelog/2022-10-11-github-actions-deprecating-save-state-and-set-output-commands/).

```yaml
name: 'Hello World'
runs:
  using: "composite"
  steps:
    - id: random-number-generator
      run: echo "name=random-id::$(echo $RANDOM)" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
      shell: bash
  ...


jobs:
  test-job:
    runs-on: self-hosted
    steps:
      - name: Call Hello World 
        id: hello-world
        uses: actions/hello-world-action@v1
      - name: Comment
        if: ${{ github.event_name == 'pull_request' }}
        uses: actions/github-script@v3
        with:
          github-token: ${{secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN}}
          script: |
            github.issues.createComment({
              issue_number: context.issue.number,
              owner: context.repo.owner,
              repo: context.repo.repo,
              body: 'Output - ${{ steps.hello-world.outputs.random-number }}'
            })
```